# ASP .NET MVC4 runtime place

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, web

I have created a silver-light website.
Silver-light has part for the client side and part for the server side.

Now, I want to crate another site in .net MVC 4.
I can't really understand two things.
The first is, where the site will be executed?? Client side or server side?? 
for example if i have a LINQ function in the controller, where it will be executed??
The second is, may i use WCF like in silver-light?? Or i can just add .edmx file(ado.entity file) in the project??

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can able to use WCF service in silver-light application. You must need to add the reference of the WCF application

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first question is that MVC is a server-side technology. You can utilize JavaScript and other methods to utilize the technology for client-side functionality, but it requires the controllers, views and models to execute on the server.

The answer to the second question is that WCF can be used just like Silverlight in MVC, although depending on how you utilize it, depends on if it is consumed on the client-side or not. If you access WCF through the Controller, its done on the server side. If you consume it through AJAX/jQuery then you are handling it through the client-side.